# How can I use itemFromIndex in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a listWidget in my form and I decided using it's

```
on_listView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
```

signal.

In the slot implementation I want to get the item that was clicked each time, and since I have the item index I thought about using

```
QListWidgetItem * curItm = ui->listView->itemFromIndex(index);
```

But I get the error:

```
'itemFromIndex' is a protected member of 'QListWidget'
```

How can I use this particular function?

Comment: You can call it from QListWidget (or derived) class only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use that particular function without deriving the `QListWidget`.

The easiest workaround would probably be simply using

```
QListWidgetItem* curItm = ui->listView->item(index->row());
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion. For the simple example that I was trying to make it is better than subclassing QListWidget. Can you by any chance imagine why that function is protected?

Comment: @dearn44 No idea why it would in any way create problems to have such a function public but the Qt guys have their reason probably

Answer (score 1):

When using the `QListWidget` just make use of the `void itemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)` signal (or Activated/Changed/...).

For using the `QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)` signal you would have to work with Sub-Class.

Comment: Yes I was aware that what you are suggesting would be the best way to do it, but I also have checkboxes next to every item and I wanted to detect any sort of clicks.